# How to recive an input from the keyboad in Maya 2016 python

Tags: python, scripting, keyboard, maya, autodesk

I wanted to know if there is an option in Maya 2016 , python script, to get the data from the keyboard, but not with opening UI windows or things like the 
'raw_input' command in python, but live, like if you play a game, and you press a button, an action is happening.
Is there a way to do that in Maya python scripting?

Comment: include code of what you have tried so far

Comment: I didn't try anything because I don't know if there is.. I looked in the internet however I found only things like the raw_input functions, which is not helpful..If you know a technique, I would be thankful if you share it here !

Comment: You don't get continous key polling with default maya. You might be able to grab the signals from the main Maya window using PySide but it's likely to be problematic because you'll be competing with the main Maya UI loop.

If you just want to do hotkeys that don't require window, just create RuntimeCommand objects

Comment: But I want to work with python, not with MEL.. Is there a way to create such objjects with python?

Comment: Pyside is a python wrapper for QT, the windowing system that run's Maya's GUI.  QT does know how to listen for input events, to listen for key presses you'd have to hack into that. You can as I said use Python to make hotkeyable RuntimeCommands which will let users trigger events from the keyboard.

Comment: @theodox        I saw that the runTimeCommand is suitable for programming in MEL in Maya, and not in Python.. Is that command works with python too?

Comment: Yep: you just use [nameCommand](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/nameCommand.html) to create nameCommand object and it will show up in the hotkey editor. The docs show how to connect it to a hotkey

Comment: @theodox       Thank you very much! But, after I created the hotkey - object, how do I tell it to move? for example if the hotkey is pressed, I want the object to move forward 10 positions.

Answer (score 1):

```
def moveCurrent(direction):
    getSel = cmds.ls(sl=True)
    if getSel:
        if direction == "up":
            currentVal = cmds.getAttr("%s.tx" % getSel[0])
            cmds.setAttr("%s.tx" % getSel[0], currentVal + 10)
        elif direction == "down":
            currentVal = cmds.getAttr("%s.tx" % getSel[0])
            cmds.setAttr("%s.tx" % getSel[0], currentVal - 10)
        elif direction == "left":
            currentVal = cmds.getAttr("%s.tz" % getSel[0])
            cmds.setAttr("%s.tz" % getSel[0], currentVal - 10)
        elif direction == "right":
            currentVal = cmds.getAttr("%s.tz" % getSel[0])
            cmds.setAttr("%s.tz" % getSel[0], currentVal + 10)

cmds.nameCommand( 'moveCurrentSelectionFuncUp', ann='Move Selected Mode', c='python("moveCurrent(\\\"up\\\")")' )
cmds.nameCommand( 'moveCurrentSelectionFuncDown', ann='Move Selected Mode b', c='python("moveCurrent(\\\"down\\\")")' )
cmds.nameCommand( 'moveCurrentSelectionFuncLeft', ann='Move Selected Mode c ', c='python("moveCurrent(\\\"left\\\")")' )
cmds.nameCommand( 'moveCurrentSelectionFuncRight', ann='Move Selected Mode d ', c='python("moveCurrent(\\\"right\\\")")' )
cmds.hotkey( keyShortcut='F5', name='moveCurrentSelectionFuncUp' )      
cmds.hotkey( keyShortcut='F6', name='moveCurrentSelectionFuncDown' ) 
cmds.hotkey( keyShortcut='F7', name='moveCurrentSelectionFuncLeft' ) 
cmds.hotkey( keyShortcut='F8', name='moveCurrentSelectionFuncRight' )
```

Make sure you have viewport focus after running above snippet.

Comment: Thank you! I have 2 questions: 1) If I want the object to move into a direction if the hot-key is pressed? How do I do that?    2) If I want a single object to have more than 1 hot-key? for example if I press W it moves forward, S moves it backwards, A  to the left and D to the right?

Comment: It worked! How ever, if I want to move the object without writing the position (up, down, right and left) in the function, how can I do that?

Comment: I don't know how you can do that, you may need to figure out :). If the answer helpful then upvote and choose as answer please :)